# Python .loc not working in custom function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I wrote a function to calculate values for a column.  The logic works great, but when I put the same logic inside a function it stops working.  Not sure why but seems like .loc is not recognized inside of the function.

```
    def capacityfunc(df, avgcol, variablecol):

        for i in range(1, len(df)):
            if (df.loc[i, avgcol] < df.loc[i-1, variablecol]):
                df.loc[i, variablecol] = df.loc[i-1, variablecol] * 1.01
        else:
            df.loc[i, variablecol] = df.loc[i, avgcol]
        return df
    df_test = capacityfunc(dfrevenue, 'AvgPercent_times_Plan', 'Plan')
```

Comment: Can you share a [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with example data?  I don't get an error with your code.  As a note: this can be done much more efficiently can Pandas.

Comment: "X stops working when inside a function" is not possible in python. so you have an error in your code which is specific to the variables in scope or the way you refactored your code. good practice in general, when coding assume that any errors you see are your fault, unless you can definitively prove that there's a bug in the package you're using. you'll get a lot farther with that assumption :) to ask us about errors you're seeing in your code, always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback). good luck!